# How can I use a "Splash" UIViewController to conditionally redirect to another view controller?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, uikit

I have a "Splash screen" ViewController extending UIViewController, set as the the initial app VC in my storyboard. This controller features a login form.

When the app starts, and before anything is displayed on the screen, I want this splash VC to check the user defaults to see if the user is already logged in. If so, I want the splash VC to redirect to the app's home VC, all before anything is displayed on the screen.

If the user is not logged in, I want the Splash VC to finish loading, displaying the login forms.

How would I go about implementing this? Would I place all of these checks in the init methods? I was having a hard time getting any code in the splash VC init methods to run at all, for some reason these methods don't get called.

Code in the viewDidLoad method runs fine, but running the code there would defeat the purpose of trying to allow the already-logged-in-user to start the app right into the home screen.

Suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My pick of the place to put this logic is in `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` of application delegate. Here is how it would look :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

        //////////////////////////////////////////////
        // 1. do loading data etc. 
        // 2. check whether user is signed in or not
        //////////////////////////////////////////////

        if(already signed in)
        {
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.window.rootViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue identifier to home VC" sender:self.window.rootViewController]; 
            });
        }
        else
        {
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.window.rootViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue identifier to login VC" sender:self.window.rootViewController];                 
            });
        }            
    });
    return YES;
}
```

And this is my quick storyboarding to assist the code. Hopefully you get the idea.

[image: Storyboard for the splash-login, splash-home]

Comment: Thanks so much. This makes sense. It was the design patterns I was having trouble with.

Comment: First `dispatch_async` is for not-blocking the process here. The splash view will not show until `application:didFinishLaunching...` exits, so your data-loading operation and login-status-check should run in the background. The two `dispatch_sync` that follow are in order to execute UI operation in the main queue. (UI operation has to run in the main thread) If you are not familiar with all this, I recommend learning about GCD. This one is a good tutorial : http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial

Comment: Would this be an appropriate situation to use Modal segues? I thought Modal segues were intended for temporary tasks intended to be dismissed later on.

Comment: Not necessarily. As you can see in this [Apple document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW1), you can present NavigationController as modal, or even chain multiple ModalViewControllers.